# How to get YTPlayer Done button state in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I am using YTPlayer for playing youtube video. video is playing correctly but when i click on Done button which method is call?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)playerView:(nonnull YTPlayerView *)playerView didChangeToState:(YTPlayerState)state;
```

This method invokes when you click on done, pause etc.

Comment: Pls add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(closedFullScreen:) name:UIWindowDidBecomeHiddenNotification object:nil];

-(void)closedFullScreen:(NSNotification *)myNotification{
    [self.playView pauseVideo];

    //required stuff here like dismissing your AVFullScreenViewController
}
```